# Binomial Expansion based on equation for evaluation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

I have this question that has really stumped me, it is supposed to be done via Binomial kind of expansion.

> If $x+\frac1x=10$ find the value of $x^3+\frac1{x^3}$.

So I hope some one has an approach to this question.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the closest thing here that looks like a binomial?

Comment: Hi Darji, just like below where one tried to expand out the x +1/x all raised to the power of 3, i got that expansion, but could not see it further(it was to much for me to write it out here). But Foobaz below did the same as i did, but after he did it, i can see how simple the solution was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$
\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3=x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}+3x^2\left(
\frac{1}{x}
\right)+3x\left(
\frac{1}{x^2}
\right)=x^3+\frac{1}{x^3}+3\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
You are given enough information to solve for the required quantity.

Comment: Thanks Foobaz, i did this same expansion and got what you got, and somehow could not see the repetitive structure of (x+1/x) somehow, which has a value of 10. I can now clearly see the solution. I guess it was one of those days where one can't see the obvious.

Comment: I will choose your post as the Answer to this question. Thanks once more Foobaz.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Expand $\;\biggl(x+\dfrac1x\biggr)^3$ by the standard formula.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to do this with a Binomial expansion but:

$x+\frac1x=10 \to x^2+1=10x \to x^2-10x+1=0$

Solve for $x$ using quadratic formula and plug it into $x^3+\frac1{x^3}$.